# Which page speed google SEO uses?

Tags: seo, googlebot

My SEO team told me Google SEO engine uses the page speed in its algo to rank the pages. It is confirmed by this [blog](https://moz.com/learn/seo/page-speed) too.

In my case, page speed is different for end-user coming from browser than google bot crawling the site. My question is does SEO uses the page speed experienced.
 by end user  or by google crwaler bot ?

Also From the blog I mentioned,  looks like it just uses the Time to first byte(TTFB) not the time taken to render/paint the dom on the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Google will use the page speed of "PageSpeed Insights". Get your blog/site speed check here and analyze the score. 
[image]

Also, google will suggest you suggestions to improve page speed, follow that :)